# Performing operation on column in bound datalist before display on front end

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a datalist that is being bound from a codebehind page (data is coming from a stored procedure). I have one column/field that I need to do some custom formatting and math on before it displays on the front end. What's the easiest way to handle this in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `ItemDataBound` event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: I don't think you can perform an OnRowDataBound on a DataList. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: I think this what I was looking for, let me try it. I prefer Gridviews myself, but I was trying to not have to recode the whole thing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class 
Bind to a List Data and then use the Property Formatted

```
public class Data 
{
    private int rawData;
    Public Int Raw Data { get { return rawData; } }
    Public String Formatted { get { return .... } }

    public void Data(int _rawData) 
    { rawData = _rawData; }    
}
```